# Having problems adding a display object in html and js, when screen-size gets to 767px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I will try my best to state my question as specifically as possible. I am having problems adding an object, in this case an icon, to the main navigation of my screen, I want the object to appear when the screen-width is reduced to 767px. The main navigation would disappear and be replaced by this object. My problem is that the icon is not displaying, whatsoever, the main navigation dissapears, but the icon does not appear. 
My code for the navigation and javascript is the following:

```
body {font-size: 20px;}

.row {padding: 0 4%;}

.col {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 4% 0;
 }

.main-nav {display: none;}
.mobile-nav-icon{display: inline-block;} 

.main-nav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.main-nav li{display: block;}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited{
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}



<div class="bgimg-1">
<div class="row">
    <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Nothing</a></li>
        <li><a href="nothing.html">Nothing</a></li>
        <li><a href="nothing2.html">Nothing</a></li>
        <li><a id="final-option" href="nothing3.html">Nothing</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.js--nav-icon').click(function() {
    var nav = $('.js--main-nav');
    var icon = $('.js--nav-icon i');

    nav.slideToggle(200);

    if (icon.hasClass('ion-navicon-round')) {
        icon.addClass('ion-close-round');
        icon.removeClass('ion-navicon-round');
    } else {
        icon.addClass('ion-navicon-round');
        icon.removeClass('ion-close-round');
    }        
});
```

Could anyone state any possible solutions as to why this is happening? I would like to tell you that I have not found any syntax errors, and that Jquery is properly implemented. If not, please check:

```
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="navigation.js"></script>
</head>
```

I look forward to hearing the suggestions from this helpful community, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need some css media query to get the ".mobile-nav-icon" link to show or hide based on screen width.

```
.mobile-nav-icon {display:none} 

@media (max-width:767px) {
.mobile-nav-icon {display: inline-block;} 
}
```

It would be much easier to debug if you put your code here in the code snippet.

Comment: I actually already have this code in, its just I had not shown all my work in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is all my code: 

    <html>
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="navigation.js"></script>

<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'; 
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #777;
}

.row{
    max-width: 1140px;
    min-width: 767px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-nav{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 55px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited{
    padding: 8px 0;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 60%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active{
    color: #666;
}

#final-option {
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.mobile-nav-icon {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.mobile-nav-icon i {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #fff;
}

.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3, .bgimg-4 {
  position: relative;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(25%);
  filter: grayscale(25%)
}

.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url("plastic-trash.jpg");
  min-height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-2 {
  background-image: url("ocean.jpg");
  min-height: 42%;
}

.bgimg-3 {
  background-image: url("octupus.jpg");
  min-height: 42%;
}

.bgimg-4 {
    background-image: url("sperm-whale.jpg");
    min-height: 70%;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.caption span.border {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

h3 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 20px "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #111;
}

                                            /* ------------Queries------------ */


/* Small phones to small tablets (481 to 767)*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
    body {font-size: 20px;}

    .row {padding: 0 4%;}

    .col {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 4% 0;
     }

    .main-nav {display: none;}
    .mobile-nav-icon{display: inline-block;} 

    .main-nav {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 35px;
        margin-right: 25px;
    }

    .main-nav li{display: block;}

    .main-nav li a:link,
    .main-nav li a:visited{
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px 0;
        font-size: 100%;
    }

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bgimg-1">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Nothing</a></li>
            <li><a href="nothing.html">Nothing</a></li>
            <li><a href="nothing2.html">Nothing</a></li>
            <li><a id="final-option" href="nothing3.html">Nothing</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="color: #777;background-color:white;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
  <h3 style="text-align:center;">Parallax Demo</h3>
  <p>Sample Text...</p>
</div>

<div class="bgimg-2">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">Caption</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="position:relative;">
  <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
    <p>Sample Text...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bgimg-3">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:25px;color: #f7f7f7;">SCROLL UP</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="position:relative;">
  <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
    <p>Scroll up and down to really get the feeling of how Parallax Scrolling works.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bgimg-4">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border">COOL!</span>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js:

```
$('.js--nav-icon').click(function() {
    var nav = $('.js--main-nav');
    var icon = $('.js--nav-icon i');

    nav.slideToggle(200);

    if (icon.hasClass('ion-navicon-round')) {
        icon.addClass('ion-close-round');
        icon.removeClass('ion-navicon-round');
    } else {
        icon.addClass('ion-navicon-round');
        icon.removeClass('ion-close-round');
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this:

1) Load the ionicons css with https in your header:
    `<link href='https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css'`

2) Add padding and background-color to the nav button:

```
.mobile-nav-icon {
float: right;
margin-top: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
background-color: #000;
padding: 0 .25em;
}
```

Comment: It did not appear. Thank you for your efforts.